# How do I move printing position up one line in terminal

Tags: language-agnostic, shell, terminal, pretty-print

I'm already aware of using \b and \r to move back one character and to the beginning on the line respectively.  But is there a way, (specifically in python,) to move the cursor position up 1 line?  I'm trying to avoid using curses, but if this is the best option then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cuu1` capability will give you the sequence you need in order to do so.

```
echo -e "aa\n$(tput cuu1)b"
```

Comment: Interesting, but I was honestly hoping to accomplish this without calling an external program.  If nothing better comes along I'll do this though!

Comment: I assume that I'll need to use curses then and there's no getting around it... :)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: It's not recommended that you hardcode terminal control sequences, but this may be of interest to you: Of the over 1500 terminfo terminal description files on my system, over 700 use `Esc[A` for `cuu1`, 230 use VT (`0x0B`), 181 don't have it, and 176 use `EscA`. The others use over 30 other sequences.